# How to send data from web to linux server

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, curl

I need to send data from my web interface to linux server. I am using tomcat as server. I am new to java, i visited many questions but didn't find any exact solution. Other than code i would like to see help regarding process/logic to send data on linux server. Manual i post data on server like this, that i need to post by web interface throuhg HTTP.

curl --header "Content-type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"name":"John", "id":"500", "employee":"yes","salary":"5000","dept":"accounts"}' http://serverNumericURL.com

Comment: What do you want to do ? with above?

Comment: I'm afraid you are not even educated enough to ask a answerable question. Try starting with a basic course in Java, Servlets etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a library like [apache http components](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)

Example:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://serverNumericURL.com");
httpPost.setEntity(new StringRequestEntity(jsonString, "application/json", "UTF-8"));
httpClient.executeMethod(httpPost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you would like to stick to the JDK, you could use the HTTPURLConnection as in the following link which covers both HTTP GET and POST.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/